# What does it mean when a process is HELD but not LOCKED?

Tags: kernel, freebsd

pget(9) documents the PGET_HOLD flag to mean

> PGET_HOLD       If set, the found process will be held and unlocked.

and

> For the PGET_HOLD case, it
>       is returned unlocked (but held).

What does it mean for a process to be held but unlocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sys/proc.h describes "holding" a process as holding its U-area in memory.  See definition for PHOLD() and PRELE() macros, at http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sys/proc.h#L755.